# make javascript .click(function() with php

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make a series of javascript.click functions using on a loop using PHP:

```
$("document").ready(function()
{    


    $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    })


<?php

        include_once '../admin/Clases/sql.php';
        $sql = new sql();

        $res = $sql->check("products","*","1");
        $javascript = "";
        if($res["ok"]){

            foreach($res["tabla"] as $fila)
            {
             $javascript .="$('#btn_".fila[2]."').click(function(){$('#prod_img').css('background-image','url(".fila[3].")');})";

            }
            echo $javascript;
        }

    ?>
```

but when I run it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't build javascript with php...it just creates a huge mess

Comment: Generating JS from PHP is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: I only need it to make a navigation bar using my database. Is the only thing I need. I already tried the same with a simple windows alert and it works. could be anothey way more easy to do that?

Comment: You are mixing a client (in this case) and a server side technology, avoid and rethink your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing a semicolon at the end of your JavaScript string:

```
$javascript .="$('#btn_".fila[2]."').click(function(){$('#prod_img').css('background-image','url(".fila[3].")');});";
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- HERE ^
```

Also:

- You forgot the `$` for your `$fila` php variable
- You'll have to use single quotes on your php string, and invert (or escape) the quotes inside js. Inside double quotes, php tries to evaluate variables – anything that starts with `$` (and guess what the jQuery function starts with...).

So this should eventually work:

```
$javascript .= '$("#btn_'.$fila[2].'").click(function(){$("#prod_img").css("background-image","url('.$fila[3].')");});';
```

---

However it's ugly as hell. I'd tackle this problem by passing your data to js as JSON, instead of writing js code from php.

Comment: any way this is the message I recive

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in C:\wamp\www\mypage\products.php on line 31

Comment: You're also forgetting the `$` for your `$fila` php variable

Comment: you're so right. I already corretd that. but why I receive problems from the $ symbols?

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. You'll have to use single quotes on your php string, and invert (or escape) the quotes inside js: `$javascript .= '$("#btn_'.$fila[2].'") ... etc ...`. Inside double quotes, php tries to evaluate variables (anything that starts with `$` --  and guess what the jQuery function starts with...)

Comment: thank you for all your help. Now I don't receive that message but It still doesn't work. I use a alert box to return the $javascript content but it neither pops up. Really I don't know why this time.
I think it's time to search for another solution =/

Comment: My bad bfavaretto. I was wrong! it worked!!. my mistake is that I used images with the .png at the end and... well that doesn't work in javascript. Thanl you very much =D

Comment: Good! But it must have been something else, javascript has no problem with png images... @user1984838